# Django how to send a argument in handler404?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, python-3.5

How can I override `handler404` to pass arguments into a view?

I need to pass the arguments `text` and `error`

```
# views.py
def handler404(request, error, text):
    response = render_to_response('error/40X.html', {'error': error, 'text':text})
    response.status_code = error
    return response
```

The 404 handler code in urls.py is:

```
handler404 = 'app.views.handler404'
```

I am using Django v1.10 and Python v3.5, and would prefer avoiding having to create a function for each error.

> The question was translated, and I would be grateful for corrections, [original](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568820/django-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-handler404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom `handler404` view here. Django's `page_not_found` view does what you want.

In Django 1.9+, you can include `{{ exception }}` in the 404 template.

In your view, you could set the message when raising the exception, for example:

```
from django.http import Http404

def my_view(request):
    raise Http404('custom error message')
```

It doesn't make sense to set `response.status_code` in the handler - if it's handler404, then the status code should always be 404.

Comment: The handler404 is for status code 404. There are [other handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#error-handling) for other codes.